# google colaboratory でgmail APIを使いたいのですが認証の途中でエラー

Tags: oauth, google-colaboratory, gmail-api

google colaboratoryでgmail APIを使いたく、以下のように実行したのですが、認証の途中でエラーとなり、どのようにしたらよいか教えていただけますでしょうか。

１．google cloud platformでoauth2.0クライアントIDを作成し（デスクトップクライアント）、jsonファイルをcolaboratoryにマウントしたgoogleドライブ上に保存。

２．以下のサイトのStep１、２のコードサンプルをほぼ丸写ししてpythonのコードを実行
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python?hl=ja

３．認証のため以下の操作をしました。
・「Please visit this URL to authorize this application:https://・・・」と認証画面のリンクが表示、
・リンク先で「アカウントの選択」、
・「このアプリは Google で確認されていません　現在テスト中のアプリへのアクセスが許可されました。招待元のデベロッパーを信頼できる場合のみ、続行してください。」画面でcontinue、
・「～が Google アカウントへのアクセスを求めています」画面で「アクセスできる情報」を選択

４．エラー
「このサイトにアクセスできませんlocalhost で接続が拒否されました。・・・ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED」

なるべく要約しようと思いましたが、長文となり申し訳ございません。よろしくお願いいたします。

---

コメントありがとうございます。以下のようなコードです。

```
pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client google-auth-httplib2 google-auth-oauthlib

from __future__ import print_function
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials

from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import base64


# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send']

def create_message(sender, to, subject, message_text):
    message = MIMEText(message_text)
    message['to'] = to
    message['from'] = sender
    message['subject'] = subject
    return {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_string().encode()).decode}

def send_message(service, user_id, message):
    try:
        message = (service.users().messages().send(userId=user_id, body=message)
                    .execute())
        print( 'Message Id: %s' % message['id'])
        return message
    except errors.HttpError as e:
        print( 'An error occurred: %s' % error)

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Gmail API.
    Lists the user's Gmail labels.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                '/content/drive/MyDrive/*****/******.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)

    sender = 'hayamaya18@gmail.com'
    to = 'rabewato@mbox.re'
    subject = 'テストメール'
    message_text = 'これはGmail APIによるテストメールです。'

    message = create_message(sender, to, subject, message_text)
    send_message(service,'me',message)

main()
```

Comment: 「以下のサイトのStep１、２のコードサンプルをほぼ丸写ししてpythonのコードを実行」では、どのようなプログラムを実行したのかが判りません。
実際に実行したプログラムを質問に追加して下さい。

Answer (score 0):

Androidで同じくGmail APIを扱ったことがあり、同様の問題を抱えたことがありました。

テスト中のアプリに、テストユーザがアクセスするためには、
・テストユーザ側の認可
・プロジェクト側のテストユーザの登録
の2つが必要となります。

Google Cloud Platform　に　Gmail APIを利用するためのプロジェクトを起こしているかと思いますが、
「APIとサービス」 → 「OAuth同意画面」にテストユーザを登録する箇所がありますので、こちらにテストユーザを追加してみてください。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

（プラットフォームにより上記の解答が誤りでしたらすみません）

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
まだテスト用で、自分のgoogleアカウント（colaboratory、google cloud platform）１つのみユーザー情報に入れている状態なのですが、追加するユーザーとはどのようなユーザーでしょうか。

Comment: 解答にある「OAuthユーザの上限」画面に、ご自分のGoogleアカウントはテストユーザとして登録されておりますでしょうか？APIのテストをするためのユーザを登録する必要があります。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。 「OAuthユーザの上限」画面に、私のGoogleアカウントをテストユーザとして登録しています。